# jquery formwizard last step sum of all the previous steps

Tags: jquery, formwizard

has anyone used the formwizard plugin and had a last step that was a confirmation step of all the entries on the previous steps?  if so how would you recommend handling that?  i was looking at a few options, but not sure which is the best route to pursue with the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer on the http://thecodemine.org/examples/example_19_summary_page.html

hard when the company blocks thecodemine.org website.......